# $Var(Q)=2\ tr(A\Sigma A\Sigma)+4\mu^TA\Sigma A\mu$

Tags: matrices, statistics

> Suppose $X\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ . $A$ is a $p\times p$ symmetric matrix . $Q$ is defined as $Q=X^TAX$. Also $Y$ be defined as $Y=X-\mu$.
>
> Show that $Var(Q)=2\ tr(A\Sigma A\Sigma)+4\mu^TA\Sigma A\mu$

Can someone help ? Should spectral decomposition of $A$ into eigen-values and eigenvectors be of any help?..

(I first tried to break down everything into Double-summation, so as to remove any vector of matrix, but didnt yield anything useful)

Comment: Entries of $X$ are mutually uncorrelated? $Q=Y'AY$?

Comment: @V.V $Cov(a^T Y,Y^TAY)=0$ for any fixed $a\in \Bbb{R}^p$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/259925/119261